# Very slow auto-completion in Linux for Windows

Tags: shell, autocomplete, strace, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For some reason auto-completion is very slow for me in WSL, it always takes several seconds display the result of, for example `ll ~/Te<tab>` (which would, after 2-3 seconds, print `ll ~/Temp`).

I've tried finding the cause using `set -x` and `strace` but can't see what the issue is.

With `set -x` (see output below) it's stopping at the line `+ [[ ~/Te == \$* ]]` and then again at `+ xspec=`

With `strace`, it's pausing at the `clone` lines and indeed it shows it's taking about 1.4 second at these lines.

Any idea what could be the issue?

**set -x**

```
+ _init_completion -s
+ local exclude= flag outx errx inx OPTIND=1
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ case $flag in
+ split=false
+ exclude+==
+ getopts n:e:o:i:s flag -s
+ COMPREPLY=()
+ local 'redir=@(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)'
+ _get_comp_words_by_ref -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ local exclude flag i OPTIND=1
+ words=()
+ local cur cword words
+ upargs=()
+ upvars=()
+ local upargs upvars vcur vcword vprev vwords
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ case $flag in
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ getopts c:i:n:p:w: flag -n '=<>&' cur prev words cword
+ [[ 6 -ge 3 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcur=cur
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 4 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vprev=prev
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 5 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vwords=words
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 6 ]]
+ case ${!OPTIND} in
+ vcword=cword
+ let 'OPTIND += 1'
+ [[ 6 -ge 7 ]]
+ __get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref '=<>&' words cword cur
+ words=()
+ local cword words
+ __reassemble_comp_words_by_ref '=<>&' words cword
+ local exclude i j line ref
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ exclude='=<>&'
+ eval cword=1
++ cword=1
+ [[ -n =<>& ]]
+ line='./rsync_tmbackup.sh ~/Te'
+ (( i=0, j=0 ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ 0 -gt 0 ]]
+ ref='words[0]'
+ eval 'words[0]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[0]=./rsync_tmbackup.sh
+ line=' ~/Te'
+ [[ 0 == 1 ]]
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ 1 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ ~/Te == +([=<>&]) ]]
+ ref='words[1]'
+ eval 'words[1]=${!ref}${COMP_WORDS[i]}'
++ words[1]='~/Te'
+ line=
+ [[ 1 == 1 ]]
+ eval cword=1
++ cword=1
+ (( i++, j++ ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ 2 == 1 ]]
+ local i cur index=24 'lead=./rsync_tmbackup.sh ~/Te'
+ [[ 24 -gt 0 ]]
+ [[ -n ./rsync_tmbackup.sh ~/Te ]]
+ [[ -n ./rsync_tmbackup.sh~/Te ]]
+ cur='./rsync_tmbackup.sh ~/Te'
+ (( i = 0 ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 24 -ge 19 ]]
+ [[ ./rsync_tmbackup.sh != \.\/\r\s\y\n\c\_\t\m\b\a\c\k\u\p\.\s\h ]]
+ [[ 0 -lt 1 ]]
+ local old_size=24
+ cur=' ~/Te'
+ local new_size=5
+ index=5
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ 5 -ge 4 ]]
+ [[  ~/T != \~\/\T\e ]]
+ cur='~/Te'
+ (( index-- ))
+ [[ 4 -ge 4 ]]
+ [[ ~/Te != \~\/\T\e ]]
+ [[ 1 -lt 1 ]]
+ (( ++i  ))
+ (( i <= cword ))
+ [[ -n ~/Te ]]
+ [[ ! -n ~/Te ]]
+ [[ 4 -lt 0 ]]
+ local words cword cur
+ _upvars -a2 words ./rsync_tmbackup.sh '~/Te' -v cword 1 -v cur '~/Te'
+ ((  10  ))
+ ((  10  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 2 ]]
+ printf %d 2
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:2}")'
++ words=("${@:3:2}")
+ shift 4
+ ((  6  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=1
+ shift 3
+ ((  3  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur='~/Te'
+ shift 3
+ ((  0  ))
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcur")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcur "$cur")
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ upvars+=("$vcword")
+ upargs+=(-v $vcword "$cword")
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ [[ 1 -ge 1 ]]
+ upvars+=("$vprev")
+ upargs+=(-v $vprev "${words[cword - 1]}")
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ upvars+=("$vwords")
+ upargs+=(-a${#words[@]} $vwords "${words[@]}")
+ ((  4  ))
+ local cur cword prev words
+ _upvars -v cur '~/Te' -v cword 1 -v prev ./rsync_tmbackup.sh -a2 words ./rsync_tmbackup.sh '~/Te'
+ ((  13  ))
+ ((  13  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cur ]]
+ unset -v cur
+ eval 'cur="$3"'
++ cur='~/Te'
+ shift 3
+ ((  10  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n cword ]]
+ unset -v cword
+ eval 'cword="$3"'
++ cword=1
+ shift 3
+ ((  7  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n prev ]]
+ unset -v prev
+ eval 'prev="$3"'
++ prev=./rsync_tmbackup.sh
+ shift 3
+ ((  4  ))
+ case $1 in
+ [[ -n 2 ]]
+ printf %d 2
+ [[ -n words ]]
+ unset -v words
+ eval 'words=("${@:3:2}")'
++ words=("${@:3:2}")
+ shift 4
+ ((  0  ))
+ _variables
+ [[ ~/Te =~ ^(\$\{?)([A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ ]]
+ return 1
+ [[ ~/Te == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ [[ ./rsync_tmbackup.sh == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&) ]]
+ local i skip
+ (( i=1 ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ ~/Te == @(?([0-9])<|?([0-9&])>?(>)|>&)* ]]
+ i=2
+ (( 1 ))
+ (( i < 2 ))
+ [[ 1 -le 0 ]]
+ prev=./rsync_tmbackup.sh
+ [[ -n false ]]
+ _split_longopt
+ [[ ~/Te == --?*=* ]]
+ return 1
+ return 0
+ false
+ _filedir
+ local i 'IFS=
' xspec
+ _tilde '~/Te'
+ local result=0
+ [[ ~/Te == \~* ]]
+ [[ ~/Te != */* ]]
+ return 0
+ local -a toks
+ local quoted x tmp
+ _quote_readline_by_ref '~/Te' quoted
+ '[' -z '~/Te' ']'
+ [[ ~/Te == \'* ]]
+ [[ ~/Te == \~* ]]
+ printf -v quoted '~%q' /Te
+ [[ ~/Te == *\\* ]]
+ [[ ~/Te == \$* ]]
++ compgen -d -- '~/Te'
+ x='~/Temp'
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ [[ '' != -d ]]
+ xspec=
++ compgen -f -X '' -- '~/Te'
+ x='~/Temp'
+ read -r tmp
+ toks+=("$tmp")
+ read -r tmp
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ [[ 2 -ne 0 ]]
+ compopt -o filenames
+ COMPREPLY+=("${toks[@]}")
mp
```

**strace -T -f -s9999 -p31972**

```
write(2, "\10\33[K", 4)                 = 4 <0.000098>
read(0, "\177", 1)                      = 1 <0.138708>
write(2, "\10\33[K", 4)                 = 4 <0.000326>
read(0, "\t", 1)                        = 1 <0.527121>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000017>
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000082>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000029>
brk(0x1130b000)                         = 0x1130b000 <0.000049>
getdents(3, /* d_reclen < sizeof(struct dirent) *//* 1 entries */, 32768) = 163 <0.000048>
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0 <0.000021>
brk(0x112fb000)                         = 0x112fb000 <0.000031>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000035>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000015>
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000066>
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000023>
brk(0x1130b000)                         = 0x1130b000 <0.000038>
getdents(3, /* d_reclen < sizeof(struct dirent) *//* 1 entries */, 32768) = 163 <0.000039>
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0 <0.000020>
brk(0x112fb000)                         = 0x112fb000 <0.000028>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000033>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3 <0.000053>
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10 <0.000024>
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000015>
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1 <0.000026>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000019>
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11 <0.000023>
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000014>
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2 <0.000025>
write(1, "2", 1)                        = 1 <0.000035>
dup2(11, 2)                             = 2 <0.000025>
fcntl(11, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000014>
close(11)                               = 0 <0.000019>
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1 <0.000034>
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000014>
close(10)                               = 0 <0.000020>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000016>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3 <0.000052>
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10 <0.000036>
fcntl(1, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000014>
dup2(3, 1)                              = 1 <0.000058>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000019>
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 11 <0.000038>
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000013>
fcntl(11, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000013>
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2 <0.000024>
write(1, "2", 1)                        = 1 <0.000025>
dup2(11, 2)                             = 2 <0.000024>
fcntl(11, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000026>
close(11)                               = 0 <0.000037>
dup2(10, 1)                             = 1 <0.000041>
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000019>
close(10)                               = 0 <0.000020>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000016>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000016>
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0 <0.000050>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000019>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000016>
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0 <0.000048>
clone(strace: Process 13930 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f98e14709d0) = 13930 <1.384199>
[pid 13930] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] setpgid(13930, 31972 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000166>
[pid 31972] <... setpgid resumed> )     = 0 <0.000170>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000015>
[pid 13930] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000185>
[pid 31972] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000015>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] close(5 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000197>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000212>
[pid 31972] close(6 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000211>
[pid 31972] close(4 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000312>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000203>
[pid 13930] setpgid(13930, 31972 <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] <... setpgid resumed> )     = 0 <0.000193>
[pid 13930] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000038>
[pid 13930] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000051>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x4aceb0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000015>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000015>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x4aceb0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
[pid 13930] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x45f790, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000018>
[pid 13930] dup2(4, 1)                  = 1 <0.000026>
[pid 13930] close(4)                    = 0 <0.000017>
[pid 13930] close(3)                    = 0 <0.000018>
[pid 13930] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0 <0.000013>
[pid 13930] stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000045>
[pid 13930] stat("/home/laurent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000047>
[pid 13930] open("/home/laurent/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000174>
[pid 13930] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000018>
[pid 13930] brk(0x1130b000)             = 0x1130b000 <0.000036>
[pid 13930] getdents(3, /* d_reclen < sizeof(struct dirent) *//* 1 entries */, 32768) = 1055 <0.000041>
[pid 13930] getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0 <0.000031>
[pid 13930] brk(0x112fb000)             = 0x112fb000 <0.000043>
[pid 13930] close(3)                    = 0 <0.000041>
[pid 13930] stat("/home/laurent/Temp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000114>
[pid 13930] write(1, "~/Temp\n", 7)     = 7 <0.000030>
[pid 31972] <... read resumed> "~/Temp\n", 128) = 7 <0.004531>
[pid 31972] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13930] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 31972] <... read resumed> "", 128) = 0 <0.000208>
[pid 31972] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13930, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 13930] +++ exited with 0 +++
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 13930 <0.000015>
wait4(-1, 0x7fffc3fb8170, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes) <0.000017>
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0 <0.000021>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000039>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [CHLD], 8) = 0 <0.000017>
ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP, [31972])          = 0 <0.000022>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000017>
time(NULL)                              = 1496570476 <0.000013>
open("/tmp/sh-thd-1052277775701132528", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 3 <0.000451>
write(3, "~/Temp", 6)                   = 6 <0.000093>
write(3, "\n", 1)                       = 1 <0.000051>
open("/tmp/sh-thd-1052277775701132528", O_RDONLY) = 4 <0.000979>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000057>
unlink("/tmp/sh-thd-1052277775701132528") = 0 <0.000328>
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000019>
fcntl(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10 <0.000028>
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000017>
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000019>
dup2(4, 0)                              = 0 <0.000036>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.000025>
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fffc3fb88f0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) <0.000040>
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0 <0.000018>
read(0, "~/Temp\n", 128)                = 7 <0.000043>
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fffc3fb88f0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) <0.000015>
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 7 <0.000015>
read(0, "", 128)                        = 0 <0.000028>
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0 <0.000135>
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000019>
close(10)                               = 0 <0.000020>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0 <0.000014>
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0 <0.000049>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000018>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000016>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [INT CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000014>
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0 <0.000065>
clone(strace: Process 13931 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f98e14709d0) = 13931 <1.379717>
[pid 13931] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] setpgid(13931, 31972 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] <... rt_sigprocmask resumed> NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000206>
[pid 31972] <... setpgid resumed> )     = 0 <0.000197>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000018>
[pid 13931] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000193>
[pid 31972] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000016>
[pid 31972] close(5 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000164>
[pid 31972] close(6 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000236>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000160>
[pid 31972] close(4 <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0},  <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] <... close resumed> )       = 0 <0.000128>
[pid 31972] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] <... rt_sigaction resumed> {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000199>
[pid 13931] setpgid(13931, 31972)       = 0 <0.000021>
[pid 13931] close(5)                    = 0 <0.000024>
[pid 13931] close(6)                    = 0 <0.000033>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x4aceb0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000017>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_IGN, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000017>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x4aceb0, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000016>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x447ad0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000019>
[pid 13931] rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x45f790, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f98e0a254b0}, 8) = 0 <0.000014>
[pid 13931] dup2(4, 1)                  = 1 <0.000028>
[pid 13931] close(4)                    = 0 <0.000020>
[pid 13931] close(3)                    = 0 <0.000021>
[pid 13931] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8) = 0 <0.000019>
[pid 13931] stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000048>
[pid 13931] stat("/home/laurent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000046>
[pid 13931] open("/home/laurent/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3 <0.000181>
[pid 13931] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000020>
[pid 13931] brk(0x1130b000)             = 0x1130b000 <0.000040>
[pid 13931] getdents(3, /* d_reclen < sizeof(struct dirent) *//* 1 entries */, 32768) = 1055 <0.000039>
[pid 13931] getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0 <0.000034>
[pid 13931] brk(0x112fb000)             = 0x112fb000 <0.000036>
[pid 13931] close(3)                    = 0 <0.000054>
[pid 13931] write(1, "~/Temp\n", 7 <unfinished ...>
[pid 31972] <... read resumed> "~/Temp\n", 128) = 7 <0.004304>
[pid 13931] <... write resumed> )       = 7 <0.000231>
[pid 31972] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 13931] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 31972] <... read resumed> "", 128) = 0 <0.000281>
[pid 31972] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=13931, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
[pid 13931] +++ exited with 0 +++
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = 13931 <0.000020>
wait4(-1, 0x7fffc3fb8090, WNOHANG|WSTOPPED|WCONTINUED, NULL) = -1 ECHILD (No child processes) <0.000023>
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0 <0.000026>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000048>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0 <0.000028>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD TSTP TTIN TTOU], [CHLD], 8) = 0 <0.000035>
ioctl(255, TIOCSPGRP, [31972])          = 0 <0.000039>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [CHLD], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000024>
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0 <0.000020>
time(NULL)                              = 1496570477 <0.000039>
open("/tmp/sh-thd-2104555551446992382", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_TRUNC, 0600) = 3 <0.000467>
write(3, "~/Temp", 6)                   = 6 <0.000106>
write(3, "\n", 1)                       = 1 <0.000062>
open("/tmp/sh-thd-2104555551446992382", O_RDONLY) = 4 <0.000707>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000050>
unlink("/tmp/sh-thd-2104555551446992382") = 0 <0.000295>
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000018>
fcntl(0, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10 <0.000025>
fcntl(0, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000014>
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000019>
dup2(4, 0)                              = 0 <0.000031>
close(4)                                = 0 <0.000024>
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fffc3fb8810)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) <0.000019>
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0 <0.000015>
read(0, "~/Temp\n", 128)                = 7 <0.000042>
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fffc3fb8810)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device) <0.000017>
lseek(0, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 7 <0.000014>
read(0, "", 128)                        = 0 <0.000028>
dup2(10, 0)                             = 0 <0.000120>
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000014>
close(10)                               = 0 <0.000019>
open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3 <0.000057>
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000017>
fcntl(2, F_DUPFD, 10)                   = 10 <0.000027>
fcntl(2, F_GETFD)                       = 0 <0.000017>
fcntl(10, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)          = 0 <0.000017>
dup2(3, 2)                              = 2 <0.000031>
close(3)                                = 0 <0.000024>
dup2(10, 2)                             = 2 <0.000038>
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC) <0.000017>
close(10)                               = 0 <0.000025>
stat("~/Temp", 0x7fffc3fb9a80)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory) <0.000070>
stat("/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000050>
stat("/home/laurent", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=512, ...}) = 0 <0.000041>
stat("/home/laurent/Temp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000130>
lstat("/home/laurent/Temp", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=11, ...}) = 0 <0.000038>
stat("/home/laurent/Temp", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 <0.000104>
write(2, "mp", 2)                       = 2 <0.000056>
read(0,
```

Comment: What shell are you using? What completion configuration do you have set up for it?

Comment: I'm using Bash with ConEmu, with the default completion configuration (don't much about it so I've never changed it).

Comment: Is it definitely bash under WSL, and not some native Bash? Slow `clone` is something that Win32 has (though, not that slow) and WSL shouldn't. The `strace` pause doesn't seem like it lines up with the `set -x` pause, however, so I don't know how reliable that observation is. I don't suppose there are a lot of filenames starting with `$` in the current directory?

Comment: Yes it's definitely WSL with the built-in Bash. No there's no file starting with `$` in this directory.

Answer (score 5):

Check your PATH variable. Mine contained many entries from Windows like:

```
...:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:...
```

Remove all superfluous entries - you don't need the `WINDOWS` paths here. It should look like mine

```
export PATH=/home/bebbo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

And the performance is great.

PS: Why did using

```
sudo updatedb
```

help? Because the net shares were touched and faster for some time.

Comment: Is there a reason to think that it is related to the problem?

Comment: When you're desperate, you try something questionable. After all, both have to do with files, and it helped me. Mabye filename completion is querying the locate db somehow?

Answer (score 2):

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/13386252-filesystem-slow-compared-with-native-ubuntu-system

> We’re working on improving filesystem perf for the next version of Windows, and have deeper changes queued up for the version afterwards.

As of 2018 Feb, the slow FS is an acknowledged bug and we got promises it'll get better but apparently needs Windows changes too.

As of mid 2019, they gave up trying to fix it in WSL and WSL2 will feature an (allegedly lightweight) Virtual machine which will have much higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the recent Windows Update 2020-04 then run from `cmd.exe`

```
wsl --upgrade <DistributionName>
```

This takes a while. Once done the filesystem is way faster.